# Ramachandran Plot for specific amino acids in a pdb file

Tags: pdb

Does anyone know of a Ramachandran plot server (URL please) that allows you to display, for example, just the leucine residues in a protein structure rather than displaying all the amino acids in the pdb file? Thanks!

Paul

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/docs/UsersGuide/midas/ramachandran.html  : Usage: ramachandran [ assign ]  atom-spec
The ramachandran command shows the distribution of peptide φ,ψ angles (a Ramachandran plot) for each specified model that contains protein. It is the command-line implementation of the Ramachandran plot function in the Model Panel. A separate plot will be generated for each protein-containing model with any atom in atom-spec, and the plot for a model will contain all of its peptide φ,ψ angles regardless of which atoms were specified.